# Why is the nested loop running before the next element gets printed?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, nested-loops

```
for element1 in range(1,10,2):
    print(element1)
    if element1==9:
            break
    for element2 in range(1,element1+2,2):
        print(element2,end=' ')
```

I have recently started with python and I am unable to understand how the for loop works in this case. If we take 1 in the for loop, it runs through and gives 1 and 1,3 but then in the output we see that it starts from 1 again and not 3. Why doesn't it start from the outer loop again by printing 3 first?

Answer (score 0):

> If we take 1 in the for loop, it runs through and gives 1 and 1,3 but then in the output we see that it starts from 1 again and not 3. Why doesn't it start from the outer loop again by printing 3 first?

The next iteration of the outer loop *does* start by printing 3 first. That's where the 3 at the end of the `1 3` output line comes from. The inner loop doesn't print that.

The inner loop never prints the last number on a line. It's responsible for printing all the other numbers. `print(element1)` in the outer loop prints the last number on each line.